# Can I simplify the process of PDO methods using the custom-made php DB class?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, pdo

I've started learning PHP OOP a few days ago and while I know the main functionality about it, I decided it would be much more efficient and clean to make the class called `DB`. It would handle the connection between the database using `PDO`.

Well, I didn't find any information similar to what I'd like to achieve. That's the main purposes of this class:

1. Store all the instances of the database and the connection info
2. Be able to require a single file which contains all the created statements
3. Using different methods for each possible situation, so you wouldn't need to write the same stuff every time*

*What I mean by saying 'writing the same stuff' is that you could create a few different methods:

```
public function prepareExecFetch() { ... }

public function prepareExec() { ... }

public function fetch() { ... }
```

And somehow I'd like to connect these functions with the PDO methods, so I wouldn't need to write these lines again and again for every statement I created. `DB` class would take care of this stuff with the single method, depending what I'd like to achieve.

I try to avoid writing these lines by using `DB`:

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('...');
$stmt1->execute(array('...' => '...'));
$r1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My project is getting bigger and bigger, so, in my opinion, that's a terrible idea to put these lines of code every time I need to access some information from the database.

Currently, I'm not interested in the PHP frameworks. Before using them, I'd like to understand how it works.

Also, could you give me some ideas about the written code of mine?

```
<?php
class DB {
    private $host;
    private $name;
    private $charset;
    private $user;
    private $password;

    // I wonder how could I store all the statements here, using the
    // $stmt1 = ...; $stmt2 = ...; wouldn't work cause it has to be
    // dymanic and I can't create new properties inside any method
    private $stmts = [];

    // Not using static modifier because if there was another instance of this
    // class, then $stmtCounter variable should be resetted again to 0
    private $stmtCounter = 0;

    public function __construct(string $host, string $name, string $charset,
                                string $user, string $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->charset = $charset;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . '; dbname=' . $this->name . ';
                        charset=' . $this->charset, $this->user, $this->password);

        // While false, PDO will take advantage of the native prepared statement
        // functionality
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        // In exception mode, if there is an error in SQL, PDO will throw
        // exceptions and the script will stop running
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);        
    }

    public function execPrepareFetch(string $stmt, array $execParams) {
        $this->stmtCounter++;
        array_push($this->stmts, $stmt . $this->stmtCounter);
    }
}

// This way by instantiating multiple instances we can easily work with multiple
//databases
$db = new DB(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db->execPrepareFetch('$stmt', [':user' => 'some value']);
```

This code isn't completed, it's just my starting ideas how could I do this. I'd to get your ideas if it's worth doing that and is it even possible? Thank you :)

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Yes, but why bother PSO already has a useful and universally documented and understood OOP interface

Comment: "Currently I'm not interested in frameworks" is like saying "I want to learn how to drive, but I'm not interested in using a pre-built car. I'd rather make my own out of tree branches and hot glue." This is not the most effective way to learn. Find a framework you can live with, explore what it has to offer, learn everything you can about it, and then *if* that's inadequate *and* you understand how these things are built, by all means try and build your own.

Comment: I was in the same boat as you, uninsterested in frameworks, but I discovered I just hadn't used one I liked much. I recommend you try to look at your options, frameworks make development hundreds of times easier. Also, why reinvent the wheel for a PDO DB class? There are already dozens, probably hundreds. For example, my PDO class [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) would allow you to write the 3 lines you mentioned wanting to avoid like this: `$db->run(String $query, Array $variables);` and will automatically handle preparing the query and sending the variables separately.

Comment: Saying things like "My project is getting bigger and bigger" is a sign that you *do not* want to hand-roll your own ORM. Nobody cares that you wrote your own ORM. Your users and customers care that the application works properly and you can add features to it quickly and easily. If you spend all your time painfully reinventing the wheel you're missing out on opportunities to write code that solves *new* problems and adds actual value to your application.

Comment: @tadman No, I haven't. I haven't used any of them yet and the reason behind it is similar why I'd like to start to stop using `jQuery`, instead start learning `AngularJS` or 'React'. I think it's the time where it doesn't matter what kind of language you use, it's a bad thing to use the already created framework to make things easy. Before easy, you have to work hard.

Comment: One problem with your current code is that the connection object only exists in the constructor. But code reviews are not on topic, we really need a more specific question.

Comment: @Rupska _it's a bad thing to use the already created framework_ ... Why, and how? - _Before easy, you have to work hard._ Well, someone already did the hard work for you. Frameworks are not really "deploy and go", the good ones are fully customizable and still require hard work to use, but it also forces you to use better coding practices at the same time.

Comment: So you say I should don't care about the `DB` class? Use OOP somewhere else and instead you the framework to make it easy?

Comment: Or maybe I should start using the PHP framework and change my mind that you have to understand how it's implemented before using the framework (I mean not fully, but you get the point)? It's the similar thing: you don't have to know exactly how the car works, fully understand every component in it to use it.

Comment: @Rupska I've tried everything from Laravel to CodeIgnitor but I didn't like any of them, then I found Fat-Free-Framework and I've used it ever since. If you're interested in trying out a simple-to-use modular MVC framework, you could check out [Grump-Free-Framework](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/grump-free-framework) which is a fork of Fat-Free-Framework that I made as a project base because the original doesn't come with any sort of set structure.

Comment: @Rupska "Before easy, you have to work hard" isn't entirely wrong, but I think you *massively* under-estimate how hard software development in general is. There's an enormously daunting abstraction gradient you're going to have to explore, everything from the electrical properties of nano-scale structures on the CPU to computational theory and every step in between. It's completely wrong to think that you must start at the bottom and work your way up. You start *somewhere*, anywhere, and branch out both into the more abstract and more concrete.

Comment: @Rupska Using a framework is absolutely essential today for several reasons: You get to solve *new* problems, you get to learn from *good* examples, and you get a huge amount of baseline security built-in for free. If someone exploits your hand-rolled application it's 100% on you. If someone exploits your Laravel-based application, presuming you've followed all community guidelines and stay up-to-date with patches, that's going to be remarkable as it's a very rare event to be "first" to get hit.

Comment: It's also ironic that you say you want to stop using jQuery, which is a light-weight abstraction layer, and use Angluar or React, both of which are heavy abstraction layers. As Grumpy points out there's many, many PHP frameworks, and some are light, some are heavy, and most are somewhere in the middle. There's at least one that'll be a good fit for you, it's just a matter of trying them out, seeing code examples, or asking peers for their recommendations.

Comment: @tadman, @GrumpyCroupton: Wow, I haven't realized it's not a bad thing to start learning framework right away. Yeah, I'd like to be a decent developer like you but I guess the way I'm doing it with the `DB` class is wrong. That's like the whole library! :D Based on your opinions, the best way to learn more at the moment I'm right now, is to use some kind of the PHP framework or the ORM. Not sure, though, I guess before doing anything, I should start experimenting with the whole bunch of frameworks :)

Comment: The best way to learn programming is to *program*, and the best way to program is to use the tools that have already solved all the usual problems so you can work on solving *new* problems. Remember, a framework is open-source and if you ever want to know how it works, open it up and look inside. If you dig deeper into the code you'll come to understand *why* frameworks are more complicated than you think, come to respect all the work they're doing for you under the hood, and can even write extensions to them to fix any of the quirks they have you really don't like.

Comment: I simply would like to learn something more difficult, that's why I'm trying new things like OOP. Later some JS stuff and so on.. :)

Comment: Thanks you guys for all the answers, I'm gonna start learning new frameworks tomorrow and if I will need some help gonna come here again :)

Comment: Writing an ORM is not "difficult" because it's well-trod territory, we've been writing these things ever since objects existed, which thanks to people like [Alan Kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay), has been a long time. Difficult problems are those unique to your business case or problem domain because nobody knows how to solve those problems yet. Riding a bicycle, for example, isn't difficult so much as requires patience. Making a [flying bicycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_human-powered_aircraft) is really hard because it's not a solved problem.

Comment: @tadman It feels like you have a lot of skills, how many years have you been learning programming ? :)

Comment: Professionally? Since around 1989. In any capacity? Since the [TI 99/4A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TI-99/4A) came out. Things have changed a lot hardware-wise since then, but the fundamentals never go out of style.

Comment: @tadman " *Nobody cares that you wrote your own ORM. Your users and customers care that the application works properly and you can add features to it quickly and easily* " - this gotta be one of the best comment I've seen of SO

Comment: Gotta admit, indeed.